# How to find Key with DES, ECB hash and plaintext

Tags: encryption, des, ecb

I have two ciphertexts. Encryption algorithm: DES in ECB mode.

1. Ciphertext: 72EE3532F904CE2AAA966C723C463F294CA8AB1C11E9E0B304BBB6A8E2BD1F34
   Plaintext: DetectedSpambotsRemailedMalwares
2. Ciphertext: 90E5AE69FEC309C47D655DE91B0C900B06CF5C4D936FCD0F72EE3532F904CE2A
   Plaintext: InfectedAccountsSpammingDetected

How to find key and use it for below cipher decryption?
Ciphertext: 4CA8AB1C11E9E0B304BBB6A8E2BD1F3490E5AE69FEC309C47D655DE91B0C900B

Comment: What is the source of this question?  Homework, CTF?

Answer (score 1):

Brief look is telling me the 3rd plaintext is RemailedMalwaresInfectedAccounts. My assumption is based on the fact this is not semantically secure ECB. I didn't look up the key and I didn't compare plaintext vs ciphertext lengths, so happy to be challenged on the answer.

Comment: OK for the method. If the incorrect decryption is intentional, that's nicely played.